# Display Image on selected with JavaScript, no access to alter HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

OK so this one is tricky (I think!). **I cannot alter the below HTML at all**, and what I am trying to do is to display an image below the drop down list below, when one of the colours is selected.

```
<div class='attributes'><b>Colour</b>

<option  value='70'>Please Select Your  Colour</option>
<option value='9016'  >White</option>
<option value='0040'  >Blue</option>
<option value='0371'  >Red</option>
<option value='0516'  >Green</option>
<option value='0356'  >Yellow</option>
<option value='0523'  >Pink</option>
```

Here's where it gets trickier; The drop-down is on multiple pages of products. I want to upload pictures, abbreviated, to match the value of the colours, and then depending on the products code, display that image from a set location.

```
<div class="code">
            <b>Code</b><br />
            FP-5
```

So, in this case, the javascript would display the image "fp-50916.jpg" when white is selected, "fp-50040.jpg" when blue is selected, etc.

I don't know if this is possible, and perhaps it is the wrong way to go about it, what do you think?

I have through some searching found this js code which has the basis I think, I unfortunately do not have a deep knowledge of js, so any help on my way would be appreciated.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
var Path='http://www.images.com/Images/';
var ImgAry=new 
Array('','9016.jpg','0040.jpg','0371.jpg','0516.jpg','0356.jpg');

function Swap(obj,id){
var i=obj.selectedIndex;
if (i<1){ return; }
document.getElementById(id).src=Path+ImgAry[i]; // I think I need to add 
something here to generate the product code infront
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: what is "id" in your code? It has to be the valid id of an existing `img` tag on the page or this can't work as it stands. From your HTML sample it looks like you haven't got one, so you probably need to create an image tag first and then insert into the `<option>` tag, am I right?

Comment: This was simply a test mockup. I am aware the JS as it stands does not function

Comment: So if you create an image tag as I suggested, does it work? Like I said, I don't know what you've already got, or not got, on your page. The example is effectively incomplete. It's hard to suggest an answer without knowing the full circumstances.

Comment: Hi ADyson, sorry for a late reply. I cannot alter the HTML at all unfortunately. I simply need to create a javascript that will display an image from a certain source, and that source would be defined by the product code on the page (in text format); and the colour selected from the drop down. Hope this makes sense

Comment: For example, if the product code was HELLO, and the colour selected from the drop-down menu was White, then it would display HELLO9016.jpg from www.websitewithallimagesuploaded.com/folder/HELLO9016.jpg

Comment: ok so sounds like you need to _create_ the img tag, and insert it into the DOM somewhere. Presumably there's an existing element on the page you have in mind, into which it should be appended? At the moment the code is trying to find an existing img tag on the page, which (I think) you're saying doesn't actually exist yet. The HTML in your example is invalid (no `<select>` element wrapping the options, and incomplete div tags), so it's difficult to understand your page structure and where you need the image to go.